# Error when executing npm start in plutus-playground-client

Tags: plutus-playground, nix-shell

I get this error when I try to execute npm start in the plutus-playground-client directory

10% building 0/1 entries 0/0 dependencies 0/0 modulesℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at https://0.0.0.0:8009/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /root/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client/dist
✖ ｢wdm｣: WARNING in Src   Lib    All
Warnings   0     0/28   0/28
Errors     0     0      0

59 WARNINGS in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)

---

### ERROR in ./static/main.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleError: Module Error (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/root/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
at Object.emitError (/root/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:525:6)
at getSassImplementation (/root/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/utils.js:55:21)
at Object.loader (/root/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:27:59)

2 ERRORS in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 3 errors and 60 warnings
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

---

If I go to https://0.0.0.0:8009/ it seems the plutus playground it's working but I can't see anything in the page. I would be really grateful if someone has figured it out this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this in the `nix-shell` of plutus-apps and run with `GC_DONT_GC=1 npm start`